# Magento Data Migration Tool For Third Party Extension or Custom Modules

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, data-migration-tool

I have done default migration using Data Migration Tool.
Now I want to migrate data of my custom module for that I am following below link:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/extend-the-tool.html

But, How can I run migrate:data command only for my custom module, As I don't want the command remigrate all data like customers, products, orders etc.

Let me know how can I run it for my custom modules only.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a different configuration file for your entities only.
In the link you referenced  there is a section that explains how to create the migration configuration for a custom entity: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/extend-the-tool.html#create-a-custom-step

It says to create a section in the config.xml file that you are using, but you can actually create a separate config file with just your entities.
Following the example in the docs, your new config file can be called `blog_migration_config.xml` and it can looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_DataMigrationTool:etc/config.xsd">
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="GreatBlog Step">
            <integrity>Vendor\Migration\Step\GreatBlog\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Vendor\Migration\Step\GreatBlog\Data</data>
            <volume>Vendor\Migration\Step\GreatBlog\Volume</volume>
         </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="GreatBlog Step">
            <delta>Vendor\Migration\Step\GreatBlog\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Vendor\Migration\Step\GreatBlog\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="..." name="...." user="...." />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="...." name="...." user="...." password="..." />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <greatblog_map_file>app/code/Vendor/Migration/etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-greatblog.xml</greatblog_map_file>
    </options>
</config>
```

Create your `map-greatblog.xml` file also to map your data structure from magento 1 to magento 2 following the guidelines in the docs.

and you can run the migration command with your config file

> bin/magento migrate:data [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] {}

Comment: Thank you.  I have run below command for my custom data migration php bin/magento migrate:data -a "app/code/Project/Migration/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/blog_migration_config.xml" --reset
Got below error:

In Map.php line 92:
                        
  XML file is invalid.

Comment: I have added steps like             <integrity>Project\Migration\Step\GreatBlog\Integrity</integrity> I replaced the Vendor with Custom namespace that I am created while overriding config.xml & map.xml for data migration tool as the blog_migration_config.xml and all other files also reside into this module. Is I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: I have not added any map.xml file path in options of my custom config.xml file, then why the map.php file error?

Comment: Do I need to add custom map.xml or class-map.xml files

Comment: I donțt remember exactly, but the basic idea would be to start from the original config.xml file, add your own config as recommended and then remove the core steps

Comment: Thanks Marius, I exactly have done this. First I have created a custom module then copy the config.xml & map.xml files and do the needful change and run migration for all default, Then create custom config.xml as you mentioned and created required file for custom step. then Run migration:data command for that custom config file and got error message : In Map.php line 92: XML file is invalid. So asking do I need to create custom map.xml, class-map.xml files too?